# Can't POST to Web Api Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to do a post request to a method in my Web API, but I'm getting a error `405: Method not allowed`. Using Fiddler I can tell that the more specific error message is `The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'`. I've tried different ways of going about it, to enable POST, but it doesn't seem to work.

The method in my API:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetOrders(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    // logic
    // logic
    // logic

    return Json(orders);
}
```

and I'm calling it in my view, using `$.post`. This works well if I have the API method in the same file as the view, but as soon as I break it out, and put `GetOrders()` in the API, it breaks and doesn't allow POSTs. Is there something I'm missing, in order to be able to post to my method? CORS is enabled in web.config, and I've tried setting it above my method with `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`, but that doesn't seem to want to play either.

Comment: Your GetOrders method doesn't accept any data, then why don't you change it to HttpGet method?

Comment: I oversimplified my example, I'll edit it. `GetOrders()` actually takes parameters, I just rewrote an example method to demonstrate my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you Web.Config

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

You don't need to decorate action by **[EnableCors]**

Also passing separate string, try to pass model

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetOrders(MyModel model)
{
    // logic
    // logic
    // logic

    return Json(orders);
}

public class MyModel{
    public string string1 {get;set;}
    public string string2 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Those three are already in my Web.config, so this isn't working.

Comment: I've tried by replacing model as a parameter and it is working for me